# Getting error while setup jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

```
$ cmd.exe /C "D:\SW\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\bin\ant.bat axc - Functional Suite && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"

Unknown argument: -
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]

Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

All setup configured properly.

Comment: It looks like `ant.bat axc - Functional Suite` is not that properly configured.

Comment: Try to execute the command directly from the command line first.

Comment: If it is one argument, quote it. Else can you inline the `ant.bat`

Comment: The target name was given wrong that the issue, if target name was correct then it is working fine, Thanks for Reply.